# Java synchronization: how to have waiting threads not execute the synchronized task

Tags: java, synchronization

Suppose I have a piece of code in Java that I want to be executed synchronously, however when the thread that owns the lock releases that lock, I do not want waiting threads to execute the synchronized code any more. I just want them to wait until the synchronized code has finished running.

So, when thread 1 enters the synchronized code (method, code block) it must get a lock on that code. Any subsequent threads must then wait for the first thread to finish running the code. So far, regular code synchronization.

However in my case, when the first thread is finished, and releases the lock, I want the waiting threads to skip that synchronized piece of code (the code updates a resource that is used by all threads).

How would I go about creating this in Java using the synchronization features? Currently I am not using the sync features, instead I am using a concurrent collection holding the lock (context), like herebelow. However, the process of locking still needs to be synchronized somehow, because two threads are able to get a lock on the context.

Cheers!

Kjeld

```
    /*
     * A concurrently accessible set of contexts.
     */
    private static final Set<String> LOCKED_CONTEXTS;

    static {
        LOCKED_CONTEXTS = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet(); // meanwhile, I replaced this with Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>()) 
    }

...

        if (!LOCKED_CONTEXTS.contains(context)) {

            LOCKED_CONTEXTS.add(context);
            log.debug("Locked context: {}", context);

            try {
                doTask();

            } finally {

                LOCKED_CONTEXTS.remove(context);
                log.debug("Released context: {}", context);
            }
        } else {

            log.debug("Waiting for context to be released: {}", context);

            while (LOCKED_CONTEXTS.contains(context)) {
            }

            log.debug("The waiting is over, context is released: {}", context);
        }
```

Comment: Meanwhile, I got the above workaround to do what I want, by replacing the concurrent set with a synchronized set. But the workaround is not ideal for me. Looking into the Semaphore suggestion right now...

Comment: Synchronisation is on one object, for miscellaneous pieces of code. Here is seems to concern one piece of code, a critical region? Often one sees after synchronized an if statement, the condition mirroring the first walk-through having produced a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't fully understand your use-case, but from what I get you want a piece of code to only run once for all triggers during its execution, but again if any trigger happens outside of the previous execution window.

Does this cover it?

```
class Work {
  private volatile boolean done;

  void queueWorkOnce() {
    done = false;
    actualWork();
  }

  private synchronized void actualWork() {
    if (!done) {
      //TODO: do work
      done = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems very useful. However, the behaviour must be dependedent on a given context string. So I am thinking, can I perhaps replace the boolean 'done' with a Map<String, Boolean> , that holds a reference between the string and it's boolean state?

Comment: just make to place the lock on whatever you need to be uniquely executed. So if's per context you can use sychronized(contextString) {} instead of on the method level. Personally I would probably prefer to make a Work object per context though if this is possible as this is better form.

Comment: I am accepting this answer (next to other very good suggestions) because I managed to use your solution succesfully in a broader scope, by applying it to contexts (as requested). A question remains: can you elaborate on why it is necessary to use the volatile keyword?

Comment: It actively disallows VMs from any in-method level caching of object level variable values, keeping you safe from missing variable updates on object level variables from different threads. Therefore I generally include it on variables that are mutated by different threads, also to mark them as such to other devs. In this case preventing a (theoretical) "false" value from being dirty-read in case the value copy happened before the lock. Something that is probably not even allowed by JVM specs, just not 100% sure about so better to add it I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to combine a lock with a semaphore.

- `tryLock` on the lock
- if you got it, do work. At the end of the work, mark the semaphore as complete
- if you did not get it, wait for the semaphore to complete

Comment: Or a [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), given that is explicitly documented as having "the same basic behavior and semantics as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized methods and statements, but with extended capabilities", where `tryLock` is one of those capabilities.

Comment: Ok cool, but how would I get a context-specific lock? Let's say a thread has a lock on context='abc', so other threads have to wait for that to be released, however another context 'def' is not locked, so that one is allowed to be claimed by the current thread, if the context is 'def'. Maybe write my own context-specific ReentrantLock implementation?